# How to highlight Go language syntax in Rider IDE

Tags: go, syntax-highlighting, rider

I have a C# project in RIDER

I need to work with some GO code within my C# project in RIDER
The GO code is not running - just there because we need to show it in the UI when the program will run.

How can I make RIDER highlight the GO language syntax while developing ?

I have the GoLand IDE - but its not what I need.....
I would like Rider to color the text

What plugin is needed ?
And how to install it ?

[image]

Comment: One way is to use the Go plugin, but I don't think it'll work in Rider. You'll need Goland or IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: "and how to install it" - if such plugin exists, it'll likely be available through the plugin management UI.

Comment: I tried to deploy the following with Rider: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047-go-language-golang-org-support-plugin But with no success. what am I missing?

Comment: Hm, it declares that it's compatible with Rider. In this case, I have no idea. I thought it's product-locked to goland and ultimate. You have restarted the IDE after installing this plugin, yes?

Comment: yes - restarted

Comment: It's an OLD plugin for OLD IDE versions (before it became standalone IDE). Now it's GoLand or IntelliJ Ultimate only. New plugin is located here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go

Comment: Check this blog post as well: https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2017/12/01/clarification-on-go-support-plugin-availability-in-intellij-based-ides/